# Azure Databricks cluster init script - Install wheel from mounted storage

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a python wheel uploaded to an azure storage account that is mounted in a databricks service. I'm trying to install the wheel using a cluster init script as described in the databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html).

My storage is definitely mounted and my file path looks correct to me. Running the command `display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/package-source"))` in a notebook yields the result:

```
path: dbfs:/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl
name: parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I have tried to install the wheel from a cluster init file using this command:

```
/databricks/python/bin/pip install "dbfs:/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl"
```

but the cluster fails to start. It's logs give me an error saying it can't find the file:

```
WARNING: Requirement 'dbfs:/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs:/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl'
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
/databricks/python/bin/pip install /mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

but I get a similar error:

```
WARNING: Requirement '/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/package-source/parser-3.0-py3-none-any.whl'
```

I've even tried using relative paths such as `../../mnt/package-source/...` but to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Related question: [Azure Databricks cluster init script - install python wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077447/azure-databricks-cluster-init-script-install-python-wheel/61085054#61085054)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using a relative path. It turns out `../../mnt/` wasn't the correct path. It worked using `../../../dbfs/mnt/`. It just took a bit of exploring the file system using the bash `ls` command to find it.

For anyone else experiencing the same problem, I suggest starting with something like this in a notebook:

```
%%sh
ls ../../../
```

Comment: If you want to use the full path, try using `pwd` in the cell, then figure out where the mount point is from there. In my case, I was looking for `/FileStore`, which is at `/dbfs/FileStore/` once I resolved the `..` path parts with my cwd to make an absolute path. (`/dbfs/mnt/` was also there.)