# Executing python code present on azure storage using databricks cluster

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

We are having code structure like
[image]

In pkg folder we have main.py and execute.py imports (from pkg import main.hello)

execute.py

```
from mnt.cdr.code.pkg import main

main.hello()
```

main.py

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

this code is present on azure storage and that blob container is mounted to /mnt/cdr/code..
But we are getting "mnt Module not found".

How can I run this code from blob container on azure databricks cluster?

Comment: To mount container to Azure Databricks,hope you have the dbutils.fs.mount method. please restart the cluster and check.

Comment: container is mounted correctly but cluster is not able to find mnt.cdr.code.pkg

Answer (score 0):

The Module Not Found Error usually occurs  when Python cannot locate an error. The most common cause of this error is not installing  modules required or importing a module incorrectly.

please check if all modules are imported .If all are correct  please restart the cluster and check

The  issue can be due to version of azure library  which may conflict with the already present libraries.Check by  downgrading or upgrading Azure library.
Also When you try to access an already created mount point or create a new mount point, it fails with the error.

To unmount a mount point, use the following command:
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/")

check [Failure when mounting Blob storage - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/access-blob-fails-wasb)
& [bash - Azure Databricks cluster init script - install python wheel - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077447/azure-databricks-cluster-init-script-install-python-wheel)

References:

1. [azure-sdk-for-python-storage-blob-upload-download](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-python-storage-blob-upload-download/blob/master/example.py)
2. [Libraries | Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html#install-a-library-on-a-cluster)
3. [util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/libmount/python/test_mount_context.py)

Comment: container is mounted correctly but cluster is not able to find mnt.cdr.code.pkg

Comment: All the files are present on azure storage